# Keypress event on a textbox inside ASP.net Gridview

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I have a problem with keypress event on an itemtemplate such as asp.net textbox inside a Gridview.

I have 5 textbox inside the gridview. What I want to do is everytime I press enter on a textbox, it will focus on the next textbox and count the total amount and put the total value inside the last textbox.

Is there any solution how to do this from code-behind or maybe by using jquery ?

*Fyi,  I also using asp.net updatepanel inside my page.*

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvItems" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
   ShowFooter="true" GridLines="None" BorderStyle="None" CssClass="table 
   table-striped">
   <Columns>
       <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Number">
           <ItemStyle CssClass="col-md-2" />
           <ItemTemplate>
              <asp:TextBox ID="txtNumber" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
           </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:TemplateField>
       <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Amount">
           <ItemStyle CssClass="col-md-2" />
           <ItemTemplate>
               <asp:TextBox CssClass="form-control" runat="server" ID="txt4A"></asp:TextBox>
           </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Amount">
           <ItemStyle CssClass="col-md-2" />
           <ItemTemplate>
               <asp:TextBox CssClass="form-control" runat="server" ID="txt3A"></asp:TextBox>
           </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Amount">
           <ItemStyle CssClass="col-md-2" />
           <ItemTemplate>
              <asp:TextBox CssClass="form-control" runat="server" ID="txt2A"></asp:TextBox>
           </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Total">
           <ItemStyle CssClass="col-md-2" />
           <ItemTemplate>
               <asp:TextBox ID="txtTotal" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
           </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
           <ItemStyle CssClass="col-md-1" />
               <ItemTemplate>
                   <asp:LinkButton ID="btnDelete" CommandName="Delete"
                            CommandArgument='<%# Eval("t_id")%>' runat="server" CssClass="btn red btn-default btn-circle waves-effect waves-circle waves-float"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                   </asp:LinkButton>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                <FooterTemplate><asp:Button ID="ButtonAdd" CssClass="btn btn-default waves-effect waves-circle waves-float" OnClick="AddNewRowToGrid" CausesValidation="false" runat="server" Text="Add Item" />
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
   </asp:GridView>
```

Here's my javascript code :

```
function SwitchOnEnter(e, NextTextBox) {
        var keynum
        var keychar
        var numcheck    

        if (window.event) // IE
        {
            keynum = e.keyCode
        }
        else if (e.which) // Netscape/Firefox/Opera
        {
            keynum = e.which
        }
        if (keynum == 13) {
            window.setTimeout(function () {
                document.getElementById(NextTextBox).focus();
            }, 0);
            return false;

        }
    }
```

Here's my code behind to execute the jquery :

```
Private Sub gvItems_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles gvItems.RowDataBound
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        Dim txt4A As TextBox = DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("txt4A"), TextBox)
        Dim txt3A As TextBox = DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("txt3A"), TextBox)
        Dim txt2A As TextBox = DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("txt2A"), TextBox)
        Dim txtNumber As TextBox = DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("txtNumber"), TextBox)

        txtNumber.Attributes.Add("onkeydown", [String].Format("SwitchOnEnter(event,'{0}');", txt4A.ClientID))
        txt4A.Attributes.Add("onkeydown", [String].Format("SwitchOnEnter(event,'{0}');", txt3A.ClientID))
    End If
End Sub
```

I managed to move the cursor to the next textbox by using this method but the cursor only blink once then it disappeared. Looks like the enter key triggering postback.

Comment: Can you post jquery code whatever you have done ?

Comment: please see my updates